# Mutating trigger while selecting a table on delete trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, mutating-table

Kindly help with the below.
I have a table with two rows and while deleting one row I write a trigger and I want to write the records into a staging table(staging_tbl) of the other row which will be left after deletion.
But it throws a mutating trigger error which is valid. But is there a way I can avoid it and write the records into staging table only there are 2 rows in main table and one of it is deleted(and not for all deletions on the table).

```
create or replace TRIGGER a_del_trg
  after delete on item_master
  for each row

DECLARE

  l_item NUMBER :=0;
  l_item_parent number :=0;
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO tmp_chk (item,item_parent) VALUES (:OLD.item,:OLD.item_parent);

  SELECT a.item,a.item_parent INTO l_item , l_item_parent
  FROM item_master a , tmp_chk  b  WHERE  a.item_parent = b.item_parent
  and a.item != b.item;

      INSERT INTO staging_tbl
        (create_date, table_name, item_sku, if_name)
      values
        (SYSDATE, 'Item_master', l_item, 'W'); -- want to add the remaining item here
    END IF;

END a_del_trg;
```

Comment: I just want to let you know `INSERT INTO tmp_chk (item,item_parent) VALUES (:OLD.item,:OLD.item_parent);` inserts the *deleted* row, and not the left one.

Comment: Hi Hawk, Yes i'm aware. I want the left one to be inserted into staging_tbl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Autonomous_transaction)**

I reproduced your error using the following statement:

```
create table item_master(item number, item_parent number);
insert into item_master values (1, 10);
insert into item_master values (2, 10);

create table tmp_chk(item number, item_parent number);

create table staging_tbl(create_date date, table_name varchar2(30), item_sku number, if_name varchar2(10));
```

I used your trigger (after removing `END IF` residue code from the end of your trigger). I got the error `"ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it." message.`

Referring to this good explanation [Fix Oracle mutating trigger table errors](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm), one must reiterate the following excerpt:

> At the end of the day, the mutating table error is usually the result of a poor application design and mutating triggers should be avoided whenever possible.

Following the fourth option in the reference `autonomous transactions`, I rewrote your trigger as follows:

```
create or replace TRIGGER a_del_trg
  after delete on item_master
  for each row

DECLARE

  l_item NUMBER :=0;
  l_item_parent number :=0;
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO tmp_chk (item,item_parent) VALUES (:OLD.item,:OLD.item_parent);
  
  SELECT a.item,a.item_parent INTO l_item , l_item_parent
  FROM item_master a , tmp_chk  b  WHERE  a.item_parent = b.item_parent
  and a.item != b.item;

      INSERT INTO staging_tbl
        (create_date, table_name, item_sku, if_name)
      values
        (SYSDATE, 'Item_master', l_item, 'W'); -- want to add the remaining item here
commit;
END a_del_trg;
/
```

Running the queries:

```
select * from item_master;
2   10

select * from tmp_chk ;
1   10

select * from staging_tbl;
27-NOV-15   Item_master 2   W
```

**ROLLBACK**

From [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonomous-transactions):

> "... in 999 times out of 1000, if you find yourself "forced" to use an
> autonomous transaction - it likely means you have a serious data
> integrity issue you haven't thought about.
>
> Where do people try to use them?
>
> - in that trigger that calls a procedure that commits (not an error
>   logging routine). Ouch, that has to hurt when you rollback.
> - in that trigger that is getting the mutating table constraint. Ouch, that
>   hurts *even more*
> - Error logging - OK.
> - Almost everything else - not OK."

Comment: Wonderful Thanks Hawk :) Appreciated.

Comment: Hawk , I have a question. Since the data gets committed every transaction, in case i rollback data after insert the data still remains in The staging table. How do i avoid this?

Comment: @ShilN That is exactly one of the main reasons *mutating table error is usually the result of a poor application design*  Read my updated answer on this

Comment: Right.. So is there another way i can handle this?